# I get this error when trying to removing a reaction

Tags: python, vps, discord.py

I get this error when I remove my reaction for my reaction role command. The wierd thing is this runs perfectly fine on my pc but when I try running it on my linux vps I get this error. Anyone know what this is caused by?

```
Ignoring exception in on_raw_reaction_remove
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/discord/client.py", line 333, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "reactionrole.py", line 335, in on_raw_reaction_remove
    await client.get_guild(payload.guild_id).get_member(payload.user_id).remove_roles(role3)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'remove_roles'
```

Thanks!!!

Comment: Could this be a verison difference? A user is presented as NoneType object when you're missing intents, If your pc is running discord.py version < 1.5.0, you don't need intents

Comment: yes, you were right I needed to enable intents

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found out the issue, wierdly enough I need gateway intents enabled for this so I have to go apply for those at discord. Lol!

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is most likely the member is no longer a member of that guild. so using guild to get the member using guild will not work. since the member is no longer there there is no roles.

You can use this to get the user if you want to.
[`bot.get_user(payload.user_id)`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Client.get_user)

```py
user = bot.get_guild(payload.guild_id).get_member(payload.user_id)
if user: # if user still in guild
    await user.remove_roles(role3)
```